# Html.LabelFor labelText with HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently it's returning the HTML as a string. Is there an easy way to get this to properly output HTML?

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisplayName, 
                 Html.Raw(Html.Partial("_Tooltip", new Tooltip { 
                                     Title = Model.DisplayName, 
                                     Description = "This is my test description"}
                                     ).ToString())
                   .ToString())
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's returning the HTML as a string"? Do you mean it's still encoded?

Comment: It's outputted exactly like this: `<SPAN CLASS="TOOLTIP">Display Name<SPAN CLASS="TIP"><SPAN CLASS="ARROW-UP"></SPAN>THIS IS MY TEST DESCRIPTION</SPAN></SPAN>`

Comment: How would you like it to output?

Comment: That explains it. Try the answer i provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating an extension method for it, following this example: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx

With the exception that I updated this:

```
tagBuilder.SetInnerText(innerText);
```

To this:

```
tagBuilder.InnerHtml = innerText;
```

Comment: Be aware that this approach opens you up to cross-site scripting attacks by making it easier for developers to accidentally include unescaped HTML in your page. Be careful not to use this method with any user-defined data as your label text.

Answer (score 1):

How about using regular HTML?

```
<label for="DisplayName">
    @Html.Partial("_Tooltip", new Tooltip { Title = Model.DisplayName, Description = "This is my test description" }
</label>
```

The problem you're running into is that the `LabelFor` helper automatically HTML-escapes the label, assuming that you're passing it just a regular string that shouldn't have HTML in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the raw html, remove the `Html.Raw()` function as follows:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisplayName, Html.Partial("_Tooltip", new Tooltip { Title = Model.DisplayName, Description = "This is my test description" }).ToString().ToString())
```

Comment: I had previously tried it without the Html.Raw as well and no luck.